# SQL - Comparing between Dates in WHERE Statement not work correctly in Access DB

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I am trying to compare between two Dates in my SQL statement. The date format I use in my DataBase is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

When I write the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTableName]  
WHERE #03/10/2014# >= #02/11/2014#;
```

The result of the WHERE statement is `True` - (Not Good).
According to the format I wanted (`DD/MM/YYYY`) it should be False, But in the SQL Statement it appears in a `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

The same problem was appeared when I used the `Now()` Function:

```
WHERE NOW() >= #02/12/2014#;
```

(*Today is the 03/11/2014*)
It should be `False` because `11 < 12` but still the statement is True. (The SQL using the `MM/DD/YYYY` format).

So I Added a `FORMAT` function and now it looks like that:

```
WHERE FORMAT(#03/10/2014#, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= FORMAT(#02/11/2014#, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

This time the result of the WHERE statement is `Flase` - (Good!).
So far the Format function looks like a good solution, BUT when trying to reformat the NOW() Date, the problem is appearing again:

This WHERE statement should be `True`

```
WHERE FORMAT(NOW(), 'DD/MM/YYYY') = FORMAT(#03/11/2014#, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

But it is `False`

While this WHERE statement should be `False`

```
WHERE FORMAT(NOW(), 'DD/MM/YYYY') = FORMAT(#11/03/2014#, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

And it is `True`

(*Today is the 03/11/2014*)

We can see that the Format function not working correctly on the NOW() Date.
Is someone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

Date literals, as delimited with `#` characters, will usually interpret values of the form `NN/NN/NNNN` in `MM/DD/YYYY` format - regardless of your culture settings.

In some cases, such as when the first set of digits is > 12, the environment *may* choose to interpret the value in `DD/MM/YYYY` order just to handle the input, but this is non-standard behavior that you should not rely upon.

Specifically, MSDN documentation for [the VB Date Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx) says the following:

> You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy, for example #5/31/1993#. This requirement is independent of your locale and your computer's date and time format settings.
>
> The reason for this restriction is that the meaning of your code should never change depending on the locale in which your application is running. Suppose you hard-code a Date literal of #3/4/1998# and intend it to mean March 4, 1998. In a locale that uses mm/dd/yyyy, 3/4/1998 compiles as you intend. But suppose you deploy your application in many countries. In a locale that uses dd/mm/yyyy, your hard-coded literal would compile to April 3, 1998. In a locale that uses yyyy/mm/dd, the literal would be invalid (April 1998, 0003) and cause a compiler error.

This is true for VB, as well as VBA and MS Access.

One way to work around this is to *not* use a date literal.  Instead, consider using the [`DateValue`](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/DateValue-Function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) function to parse the string to a date object before querying with it.

Comment: So which character should I use instead of `#`?

Comment: When querying with literals, it's not a matter of changing the character.  You need to use MM/DD/YYYY format.  There's no simple way around that.  In a real application, you would be passing a variable or parameter instead of using literals.

Comment: I *think* you could also use YYYY-MM-DD format, if you want to try that instead.  Since there are four characters in the front, it will probably be interpreted correctly.

Comment: *"**always** interpreted in MM/DD/YYYY"*?  `Debug.Print Format(#25/12/2014#, "mmm d yyyy")` shows me *Dec 25 2014*

Comment: I changed the `SELECT *` to 
`SELECT *, FORMAT(Now(),'DD/MM/YYYY') AS Today` and it shows in the new column the value in the correct format

Comment: @AlonP - Yes, that will work fine for *output formatting*.  But you shouldn't do that when querying (in a WHERE clause), or it will not be able to take advantage of any indexes you might have.

Comment: I like your parameter query suggestion --- supply a valid Date/Time value for the parameter --- which neatly avoid ambiguous format issues with date literals.  Seems to me that point deserves to be in the answer.